# undefined reference uuid_generate ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, uuid

I have installed libuuid using the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
```

And is properly installed from the terminal.

Then, i include `<uuid/uuid.h>` header file.
  But while calling function uuid-generate as under it is giving  reference error

```
  uuid_t newUUID;
  uuid_generate(newUUID);
```

Comment: iSight, please post the **exact** error message you get.

Comment: @Martin: the error is undefined reference to uuid_generate

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I have resolved the above issue. Instead of using terminal to install the uuid generator, following is my step that i followed:

1. call sudo apt-get install uuid-dev command on terminal
2. Go to properties menu item, under project menu and add uuid library by selecting add package option.
3. Then do include header #include uuid/uuid.h

Comment: How is this an acceptable answer? Menu item? Add package option? This answer doesn't even mention which application was used, and won't be very helpful for anyone having similar issues.

Answer (score 17):

You have to link against libuuid (see /usr/lib/libuuid.so and /usr/lib/libuuid.a). Add linker option -luuid to tell the linker to reference the library file.

Comment: @damg: when i call -luuid, nothing seems happened.

Comment: iSight, Do `nm -D /usr/lib/libuuid.so |grep uuid_generate` and report the output.

Comment: @Martin: after generating i am getting this lines:000022a0 T uuid_generate
00001680 T uuid_generate_random
00002170 T uuid_generate_time

Comment: Argument order is (was?) important in gcc. Depending on compilation unit dependencies you have to move the linker options and objects further or behind each other.

Comment: @iSight: nm -D shows all exports and used symbols in a binary. A check whether your library ships the required symbol. man nm for additional information.

Comment: iSight: as damg says, this test shows that the library is the right one. So linking -luuid should do the trick. The next guess is that (as damg guesses) you have the argument order wrong: please show your complete linker line (edit your original post to add that information).